# Download text file when cliking link in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally I can use this line to trigger the download of files:

```
<a href={require("../path/to/file.pdf")} download="myFile">Download file</a>
```

but when the file is plain text, for example a `.txt` file, when I click on the link the file is just opened in the browser to see the contents, is there a way to trigger the download of text files too?

Answer (score 0):

the way u could do it like this:

```
<a href="testFile.txt" download rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
    Download File
 </a>
```

Remember that the dowload attribute is not supported by IE11. This why we need a target="_blank".

Comment: It still opens the file in the browser instead of downloading it. I have tried using the latest version of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Any solution on this issue?

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href={require("../path/to/file.pdf")} target="_blank">Download file</a>
```

Comment: Can you explain why this might solve the problem ?